# MSAccess: type mismatch in date column for sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

In ms-access database i have a table named tableA

this table has a column called Call_Date which has 4 types of entries

1. dates ( e.g 10/23/2008 )
2. -
3. NA
4. Blanks ( empty cell )

how can i write a query to select all rows of tableA except those where the Call_Date column has - or NA or Blanks

i tried writing

```
Select * from tableA where Call_Date not in ('-','NA',' ');
```

but its giving type mismatch error.

Comment: what datatype is the `Call_Date` field of?

Comment: I would imagine that the blanks are null, rather that a space. The line above worked for me on a text-type column (field).

Comment: @david - its date
@Remou - you are right

Comment: It can't be a date data type if it it has "N/A" or "-" in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `Call_Date` must be string type in the table.

```
Select * from tableA where IsDate(Call_Date) = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting the Call_Date field as a string

```
Select * from tableA where Cstr(Call_Date) not in ('-','NA',' ');
```

Although I would think the datatype of Call_Date should be string if it can have all those entries